# HTML Button submit not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

My HTML code is as below.

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="file2" id="FileField" value="( .xls / .xlsx )" />
        <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" style="visibility:hidden;width: 0" onchange="getElementById('FileField').value = this.value;" />
        <input type="button"  id ="browse" onclick="document.getElementById('file1').click()" />
        <input id="scan" type="submit" value="click" />
    </form>
```

When I click on 'click' button in IE, nothing happens . But the same code is working in all other browsers.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of IE? IE8 and up have a set of developer tools you can access by pressing the `F12` key. The console in those tools will tell you where the error is, if there is one.

Comment: Its not working in any version of IE. And it is not giving any error in console.

Comment: Hmm. Google says that `click()` is not the correct event. Try changing it to `onclick()`, since that's the actual method you're trying to call. I can only assume the other browsers have implemented some mapping to route to the correct event.

Comment: @Tieson T, `click()` on `Browse` button works fine. JSFiddle show, what first click on `submit` button not work in IE, but second click submitting form.

Comment: Hmm, when i remove hiding style from `file` element, I seen what if I click `submit` button first time, textfield of `file` element received focus and clear text.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="attachmentFileText" readonly="readonly" value="" />

<div style="overflow: hidden; vertical-align: middle; height: 20px; width: 72px; margin-right: 15px;" class="button" title="Select file">
    Browse
    <input type="file" name="attachmentFile" id="attachmentFile" size="1" style="margin-top: -50px; margin-left:-410px; -moz-opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); opacity: 0; font-size: 150px; height: 100px;" onchange="checkFileName();"/>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function checkFileName() {
var fullPath = document.getElementById('attachmentFile').value;
var fileName = fullPath.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
document.getElementById("attachmentFileText").value = fileName;
```

}

The "INPUT" element "attachmentFileText" will be display the our file name.
The "div" element - it is our button element to display instead of the original input.